# Why I cannot changing the permission of executing a shellscript even as a root?

Tags: shell, scripting, permissions, terminal

I have a `run.sh` file, I want to execute it from terminal by

```
./run.sh
```

However, it says

```
bash: ./run.sh: Permission denied
```

Then I tried to change the permission of executing it. I open the properties of that file, and go to permission tab, I checked the "`Allow executing file as program`". The check mark disappeared! It invalidated my check...

Then I tried to use

```
sudo chmod +x run.sh
```

and then

```
./run.sh
```

Then same permission problem happened...
However, if I run it with

```
bash run.sh
```

it works. But I really want to fix the issue and go back to my habit of using `./` to execute shellscript. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this is not the permission with respect to types, instead it is about user specific permission.

One possible explanation is your bash process might be running under root owner. Hence all applications you run as

```
bash script.sh
```

do not need superuser permission.
If you run as

```
bash script.sh
```

you need to provide root password for it to work.

Comment: Your comments seem self-contradictory: if you run `bash script.sh` you do not need superuser permission, but if you run `bash script.sh`, you need to provide a root password?  Did you have `sudo` or `su` in mind for the second one?

Answer (score 1):

Does your script run.sh have a shebang (First line of the script starting with #!) ?

Comment: Yes i do, it runs in Bash.

Comment: Could you copy/paste your shebang?

Comment: The shebang is #!/bin/bash